# Kerberos authentication in jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, kerberos

I need to setup kerberos authentication in jmeter.

According to the procedure mentioned in the link - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter, I have setup the jmeter config files - krb5.conf and jaas.conf and added http authorization manager config element in jmeter file. I am not sure about the need of putting username and password. Can someone put more insight into the setup procedure for Kerberos in jmeter?

I am attaching the details of the configuration files in jmeter.

[image: jaas.conf file]

[image: krb5.conf file]

Comment: Currently using Apache jmeter - 2.13 version

Answer (score 1):

According to the above guide you need to provide not only username and password, but domain and realm as well.

Also make sure that KERBEROS mechanism is selected

[image: JMeter Kerberos]

Also I would recommend switching to [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) which was released 6 month ago already with lots of bug fixes, performance improvements and new features.

Comment: What should be the username? Is it the SPN or the username to which the  SPN is attached?

Comment: It depends on your Kerberos configuration. Most commonly it should be the same credentials you use to log into the domain.

Comment: I tried with the domain credentials with various possibilities, i.e. domain\username, username, etc. Can you please share more details or any link that can shed more details related to the setup of Base URL, username and password details under HTTP Authorization Manager.